# Displaying a simple dialog box which takes input from user in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I am trying to display a simple dialog box on a click of button which will have 3 text boxes to take input from the user and a button which on click will store the values of textboxes in some variable. I know the same in dojo. I tried the below dojo code mentioned as below but I didn't find it to be working. How can the same be achieved using HTML/jQuery?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="layout/dojo/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true,debugAtAllCosts:true,isDebug: false,gfxRenderer: 'svg,silverlight,canvas,vml'"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/dojo/dojox/analytics/plugins/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true,debugAtAllCosts:true,isDebug: false, gfxRenderer: 'svg,silverlight,canvas,vml'"></script>     
     <link rel="stylesheet" id="themeStyles" href="layout/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" id="themeStyles" href="layout/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/document.css"/>   
     <link href="layout/css/button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <title>Dojo Dialog Test</title>


<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojox.grid.cells.dijit");
dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.require("dojox.widget.Dialog");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.cells.dijit");
dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.require("dojox.layout.TableContainer");


function createDialog()
{
     dijit.byId('dialog').show(); 
}

function closeDialog()
{
     dijit.byId('dialog').hide(); 
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type ="button" id="dialog" value="Dialog" onclick="javascript:createDialog();"> 
<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="dialog" title="tested" style="width:60%;height:70%;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a dialog box where you could input values, you could either write code using jQuery to generate the dialog box by yourself. But why reinvent the wheel when you have frameworks like jQuery UI or bootstrap. Below is a sample using HTML 5, jQuery,  [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"  ></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="themeStyles" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
    <title>Bootstrap Dialog Test</title>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var textbox1 = "";
        var textbox2 = "";
        var textbox3 = "";

        function saveTextBoxes() {
            textbox1 = $("#textbox1").val();
            textbox2 = $("#textbox2").val();
            textbox3 = $("#textbox3").val();
        }
        function alertSavedValues() {
            alert("box 1: " + textbox1 + " box 2: " + textbox2 + " box 3: " + textbox3)
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch Dialog
    </button><br>
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="alertSavedValues()">Text Box values</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Input Form</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Text Box 1 <input type="textbox" id="textbox1"> </input><br>
                    Text Box 2 <input type="textbox" id="textbox2"> </input><br>
                    Text Box 3 <input type="textbox" id="textbox3"> </input><br>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveTextBoxes()">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</body>
</html>
```